# Reading grep patterns from a file

Tags: grep

I have a couple of big text files and in the file `UNIQS.txt` I have a list of strings to `grep` from another file. The code I use is

```
grep -f UNIQS.txt EEP_VSL.uniqs.sam > UNIQ_templates.sam
```

which does nothing - the file generated is empty. But when I do

```
grep -F -f UNIQS.txt EEP_VSL.uniqs.sam > UNIQ_templates.sam
```

it works correctly. This confuses me because I didn't think `grep` would interpret the entries in `UNIQS.txt` as regexp patterns without quotes and slashes and so on being in the file (which there aren't). Is it the case in general that if you are getting the patterns from a file then it will automatically think that they are regexp patterns?

**Edit:** In the `UNIQS.txt` file, there are newline separated strings of the form

```
HWI-ST365:215:D0GH0ACXX:2:1101:10034:186783
```

(called template names) and the file `EEP_VSL...` tab separated columns, with about 14 columns and the first column is the template name, so basically I want to extract the line corresponding to each template in the file.

Comment: I had the same problem, the solution was different, though. My pattern file was produced with Windows and contained \r -> no matches in the Linux file.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

The `-f` option specifies a file where grep reads patterns. That's just like passing patterns on the command line (with the `-e` option if there's more than one), except that when you're calling from a shell you may need to quote the pattern to protect special characters in it from being expanded by the shell.

The argument `-E` or `-F` or `-P`, if any, tells grep which syntax the patterns are written in. With no argument, grep expects [basic regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended); with `-E`, grep expects [extended regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_extended); with `-P` (if supported), grep expects [Perl regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Standard_Perl); and with `-F`, grep expects literal strings. Whether the patterns come from the command line or from a file doesn't matter.

Note that the strings are substrings: if you pass `a+b` as a pattern then a line containing `a+b+c` is matched. If you want to search for lines containing exactly one of the supplied strings and no more, then pass the `-x` option.

Comment: Okay that's useful thanks. Can I ask, suppose that I wanted to match the string exactly, i.e if the string is 12345 then I want it to match on 12345 only, not on 123456 or 123455 etc., how would I go about doing this?

Comment: @sdf Read my last paragraph: `-x`

Comment: This is so old, sorry for digging it out. While the above explanation is awesome, it is a bit vague on *why* the patterns (strings) from file do not match without the `-F` flag. My guess is the `-` in the sample line above causes this to be read as a sequence of characters? Wouldn't that require square brackets too? I've tested with some sample files but haven't come to a conclusion.

Comment: @trs The line shown in the question (which was added after I posted my answer) doesn't contain any character that has a special meaning in regexps, so it behaves the same with and without `-F`. It would make a difference with characters such as `\[*^$`.

Comment: @Gilles thanks, that was my impression too but the @sdf claims "the file generated is empty" (read: no matches) without the `-F` flag?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, not solved with the good answer from @gilles.
Looking closer in the input file, I found 2 newlines at the end.
Without these, success, needed only: grep -i file_pattern_input file

(GNU grep 3.1, Input file more than 5000 records, matching/pattern file 2536, I knew all the 2536 have to be in the file. With newlines got all lines of the file and without only the 2536 matching lines)

Comment: That is unrelated to OP's problem. An empty line is read by grep as an empty pattern, and an empty pattern matches everywhere.